# How can I integrate SSO in existing ionic app?

Tags: typescript, authentication, ionic-framework, single-sign-on

I have an ionic app and I want to use SSO login in it. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Or is there any tutorial that I can follow? I have searched on the internet, and found nothing.

HELP!

Answer (score -1):

If you code does not run inside HTTPd, run on a server it supports, bound to `localhost`, install HTTPd on any Unix-like OS, join the server into your Kerberos realm, install mod_auth_gssapi, configure HTTPd to act as reverse proxy for your backend app, configure all requests to that proxied app to be authenticated by SPNEGO/Kerberos. You are done.